# Visual Studio Code and Debugpy remote debugging - "Client Authentication Failed" Error

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to perform remote Python debugging with Visual Studio Code and debugpy. I am attaching to a python script running on an oracle linux server. I am on a Windows 10 machine.

Steps followed:

1. Open SSH tunnel from my Windows workstation to the oracle linux server

```
ssh -2 -L 5678:127.0.0.1:5678 <username>@192.168.143.220 -i "C:\Users\<username>\.ssh\id_ed25519"
```

2. Place the following lines in the script:

```
import debugpy
debugpy.listen(("192.168.143.220", listen))
debugpy.wait_for_client()
```

3. run the script in debug mode (I have a virtual environment but it is not depicted)

```
python3 -m debugpy --listen 5678 email_activity_processing.py
```

4. Back on my workstation run the following launch configuration to VSCode:

```
{
      "name": "Support Robot Debugging",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "connect" : {
        "port": 5678,
        "host": "localhost"
      },
      "pathMappings": [
        {
          "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
          "remoteRoot": "."
        }
      ]
    }
```

5. Receive this error:
   [Error dialog stating: Client not authenticated. Buttons for "launch.json" or "Cancel"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NL2yt.png)

I have configured a declaration in my .ssh/config file for this server.

I have tried a few different combinations of what address to use in debugpy.listen(), and the python3 -m debugpy --listen. I followed the troubleshooting instruction here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/troubleshooting. I did not find anything in the debugpy Github repo of issues.

The remote server is running Python 3.11.

Any ideas on what troubleshooting steps to take next? Is there a way to generate or see a log from Visual Studio code of the connection attempt?

Comment: I just hit this. Did you find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

I just set this up myself, but didn't directly use debugpy. vs code did all of the work for me, and i don't have to run any commands to attach debuggers. vs code handles debugpy for you.

from start to finish:

1. install remote-ssh extension
2. Once installed, you will find a green icon on the bottom left corner in vs code which allows us to connect to the remote machine.
3. After clicking, connect to your remote machine via ssh command: ssh user@host via the prompt
4. If your using ssh key, it takes a bit of work, edit .ssh/config file. after adding the host it should pop up. IdentityFile c:/your_id_dsa file. you'll have to set yourself as the owner with read/write perms and remove all other permissions.
5. Once you are connected to remote machine, choose a spot for your files, create a python file or clone a repo, and try "running/debugging" a .py file. it will then prompt you to install a remote debugger after selecting your python location on the remote machine.
6. vs code will search for "@category:debuggers Python" click the "install on {remote}" button on the first option "python"
7. enjoy